# How to call User.Identity.GetUserId() inside a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Language: ASP.NET (VB)

I have the following code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ... 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM cust WHERE cust_id='C001';">
```

Now I want to modify it to become something like the following pseudocode:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ... 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM cust WHERE cust_id='" & User.Identity.GetUserId() & "';">
```

**where `cust_id` is a `NVARCHAR(128)`, equivalent to the user ID data type in the `AspNetUsers` SQL Server Database.**

Obviously it is wrong in syntax because it is not correct in syntax. How can I get the above idea to work?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll want to add some `<SelectParameters>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z72eefad(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your markup to:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>

<asp:SqlDataSource ConnectionString="YourConnStr" ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM cust WHERE cust_id = @CustId">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustId" DbType="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in your Page_Load in code behind:

```
Sub Page_Load()
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("CustId").DefaultValue = User.Identity.GetUserId()
End Sub
```

Comment: Updated answer, please try that.